# Copy Surface in Texture with TextureLock SDL2

Tags: c, sdl-2

Hi i want to copy a surface in a texture doing this:

```
void  copy_surface_in_texture(SDL_Texture *dst, SDL_Surface *src, int x, int y)
{
   int *pixels;
   int pitch;

   SDL_TextureLock(dst, &(SDL_Rect){x, y, src->w, src->h}, (void **)&pixels, &pitch);
   SDL_SurfaceLock(src);
   memcpy(pixels, src->pixels, pitch * src->h);
   SDL_SurfaceUnlock(src);
   SDL_TextureUnlock(dst);
}
```

But this only works when `src` has the same dimensions than `dst`, when `src` is more little than `dst` i obtain a distorsion of `src`. What is wrong in my code?

PD: I know i can use `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` but i need to perform the copy throught pixel manipulation

Comment: "*but i need to perform the copy throught pixel manipulation*" this is something that requires good justification. Your question actually demonstrates why ...

Comment: I don't get what you mean

Comment: you don't give any reason **why** you want to work directly on the pixels, but you already experience why this is complicated and error-prone -- which is the reason for SDL to offer friendly functions. If there's another problem to solve by writing your own code, you should explain that problem, in order to avoid the typical "XY problem".

Comment: AFAIK, the pixel format of a texture depends on the hardware/driver used for drawing it, so you'll have many more problems with your approach. Therefore, put it another way, I *very much doubt* it's a good idea. That's why it would be interesting to know what actual problem you want to solve that way -- there might be a much better idea!

Comment: Mmmm basically is a velocity problem, i have a lot of surfaces and i Blit all them  in one big surface and after that i use `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` but thats slower than copy pixel by pixel, with the function above, the big surface in the texture (that match in dimensions) then i thought that would be even faster if all that little surface are written pixel by pixel in the big texture then avoiding, like that, create another surface and perform `SDL_BlitSurface` a bunch of times.

Comment: I assumed something like this, but you'd have to do the same (check formats, convert like necessary) yourself, and you won't come up with better code than SDL already has. Even worse, your code will stop working on a different platform where textures have different internal representation. Instead, you could look into caching/persisting your "big surface", so you avoid unnecessary blitting.

Comment: The big surface i being updated constanly with the little ones in fact the big surface is created only one time and im blitting only the surfaces that are modified but is not as fast as i would want, but i suppose that it has nothing to do. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then maybe there's a way to work with smaller textures instead. But that's hard to know without knowing the whole design...

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez pixels are packed row-by-row (probably with a bit of padding for better alignment), so assuming formats are the same - if size is different you'll have avalanche shift with each row. You have to memcpy each row, using `row_number*surface->pitch` as byte offset of source surface. As a bit easier workaround, first thing coming to mind is creating extra surface with appropriate format and size, blitting into it, and then memcpying to texture pixels.

Comment: Wait would be more optimal
little surface -> little texture -> blit to a big texture -> Render
than
little surface ->blit to a big surface -> big texture -> Render

Comment: @keltar this still requires to know what formats are possible for textures and this depends on the hardware/driver. A portable program would have to consider this at runtime, so you're ultimately reimplementing `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`.

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez I would assume operations on textures can be done by your GPU, so I'd expect this to be faster, but I'm not sure ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes exactly but `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` is explicitly intended for static textures.

Comment: Cheking the API of SDL i have found this funcion [SDL_UpdateTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture) if i call it like this:
`SDL_UpdateTexture(dst, &(SDL_Rect){x, y, src->w, src->h}, src->pixels, src->pitch)`
Looks like it works, would be the same than doing it manually with lock and unlock?

Comment: @keltar then as you say i should copy each line of src in dst? Then should be a for that go thorught all rows of src and copy them to dst but i must to move dst the same cuantity of bytes that i have copy from src?

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez well, sounds good, just try it and measure it. It wouldn't be "the same" as I'm pretty sure SDL will correctly take care of any format issues -- something that could be very challenging.

Comment: I lost the point of conversaion. Link to UpdateTexture doc already answers that it is for static textures and therefore have very different intended use than locking, which is for streaming textures only. And that pixel format must match in both cases (but there is a `SDL_ConvertPixels` to handle conversion).

Comment: Probably i'll use `SDL_UpdateTexture` as you say i feel more secure using something designed to it than build it for myself. But anyway im pretty curious about what @keltar said of copy each row, cause `SDL_LockTexture` ask for an `SDL_Rect` then i thought that if the SDL_Rect has the same dimensions than src shouldn't have any problem, then what is happening there ?

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez draw rectangle on paper. That's your pixels. Left upper corner is 0 (origin). Each row is `pitch` bytes. Now draw another rectangle in it with different size - do you see which parts you need to skip?

Comment: @keltar oh, thats a problem because im using an streaming texture... then im in the same problem than at the begining.

Comment: @keltar okey now i understand what you mean but that parts i should skip is not precisely the reason why `SDL_LockTexture` asks for an `SDL_Rect`?. As i see it my paper is my texture and the SDL_Rect is where im gonna 'paste' another piece of paper

Comment: Ok, it's a while since I used SDL, but I **thought** the RECT here just specifies what pixels you're locking and you still get a pointer to **all** the pixels (otherwise, there would be some internal copying needed)

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez locking gives you entire region (if it can) but pointer  is shifted to match your rect's `x`/`y`. It is up to you not to exceed your rect, and respect `pitch` it have given you. I don't think it is very useful, NULL rect is much clearer to my mind, but I suppose that's the matter of preference.

Comment: @keltar then the pitch i get is the cuantity of bytes in a Rect's row or in a Texture's row?

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez it's byte offset from the pointer `LockTexture` have given you, that is second row is `(char*)ptr+pitch` and so on. Since array holds entire texture, locking 1x1 rect will still give you pitch of entire texture - it only depends on texture dimensions/format, not locked rect.

Comment: I did it, a lot of thanks !!! if you post it as an answer ill mark it as correct ^^